# How to save uploaded image to Storage in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Image intervention to save an image to the storage folder. I have the code below and it seems to just save a file name with a blank image. I think I need a way for the file contents to be written to the folder but struggling for the snippet.

```php
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $image = $request->file('photo');
    $fileName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    $img->resize(120, 120, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();                 
    });
                
    //dd();
    Storage::disk('local')->put('images/1/smalls'.'/'.$fileName, $img, 'public');
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to do

```php
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $image = $request->file('photo');
    $fileName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
    $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    $img->resize(120, 120, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();                 
    });
    
    $img->stream(); // <-- Key point
    
    //dd();
    Storage::disk('local')->put('images/1/smalls'.'/'.$fileName, $img, 'public');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I am clear what stream means or does but it's working.

Comment: An explanation as to what this actually does would definitely be useful.

Comment: It's easy to find out if you glance at the [documentation](http://image.intervention.io/api/stream)

Answer (score 3):

```php
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    // $path = Storage::disk('local')->put($request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName(),$request->file('photo')->get());
    $path = $request->file('photo')->store('/images/1/smalls');
    $product->image_url = $path;
}
```

Comment: commented one is the other way with defining disk.

Comment: above comment you should write in Answer not in comment

Answer (score 2):

Simple Code.

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
    $object->image = $request->image->store('your_path/image');
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to save images using intervention package on storage path with desired name. (using `Storage::putFileAs` method )

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {

        $image      = $request->file('photo');
        $image_name = time() . '.' . $image->extension();

        $image = Image::make($request->file('photo'))
            ->resize(120, 120, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
             });

        //here you can define any directory name whatever you want, if dir is not exist it will created automatically.
        Storage::putFileAs('public/images/1/smalls/' . $image_name, (string)$image->encode('png', 95), $image_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me in laravel 10

```
$folder = 'folder/';
$path = storage_path('app/public/'.$folder);
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = ImageManager::imagick()->read($file);
    $image->save($path.$filename);
}
```