# Use laravel storage with Image intervention canvas()

Tags: php, laravel, intervention, laravel-5.4

Running Laraval 5.4 with Vagrant and Homestead.

Saw a few other questions regarding this issue but none provided a solution which uses the [canvas()](http://image.intervention.io/api/canvas) method by Intervention/Image

Laravel introduced a [easier storage system since 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-uploads)

My current code:

```
$path = $request->file('logo')->store('/clients/logos','public');

$canvas = Image::canvas($width, $height);
$image = Image::make($path)->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint)
{
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

$canvas->insert($image, 'center');
$canvas->save($path);

$this->logo_path = $path;
```

This code creates a canvas and places a resized image inside it.

This code gives following error:

> NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 335: Image source not
>   readable in AbstractDecoder.php line 335 at
>   AbstractDecoder->init('clients/logos/UupUn1iuDGRsy5Z0bkWHJ6S4v79bfZiXapTO7vLk.jpeg')
>   in AbstractDriver.php line 64

The first line works, because the image is stored inside my storage folder at the following location:

"/storage/app/public/clients/logo/UupUn1iuDGRsy5Z0bkWHJ6S4v79bfZiXapTO7vLk.jpeg"

but the image is stored in full-size, so the code fails at the image-intervention part.

Things i tried:
I tried changing the `$path` variable inside Image::make() to this:

```
Storage::disk('public')->url($path)
```

which results in following error:
Can't write image data to path

> (http://test.dev/storage/clients/logos/owjNA5Fn9QyYoS0i84UgysaFLo5v0NzbOiBhBzXp.jpeg)

The weird part about that error is that the 'app' directory is not visible inside that error.

I'm running out of ideas to solve this issue.

### Edit

Got it working without using canvas, but still would like to know a way to use canvas()

This is how i currently got it working:

```
$path = $logo->hashName('public/clients/logos');

$image = Image::make($logo);

$image->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint)
{
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

Storage::put($path, (string) $image->encode(), 'public');

$this->logo_path = $path;
```

#### Retrieving the image

```
{{Storage::url($client->logo_path)}}
```

Comment: I believe this is a file permission issue. Try setting the storage with a proper user privileged.

Comment: the image is saved inside the storage folder, just nog resized. So it can write to the folder. I tried setting it to 777 but that also didn't solve the issue

Comment: I'm guessing that's because of the `$path` variable. Check it here: [Refence #1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468437/getting-error-notreadableexception-in-abstractdecoder-php-line-302/33469360#33469360) or you might try what this guy did in [Reference #2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990023/how-to-save-uploaded-image-to-storage-in-laravel). Best of luck.

Comment: @Christophvh what is laravel version? The title contains `5.3`, but tags are with `5.4` in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought was that you have a typo - code contains both `logo` and `logos` paths.

Then I installed laravel with canvas and got the same error. So I've just made a little path improvements and now it works. The key point is that *the returned $path is relative not to your storage path but to storage/app/public*.

```
$width = 50;
$height = 50;

// here $path is set to "clients/logos/FWGXEf9AJ0NOspFoxelTtGUqmr0YP4ztUMUcqkXc.png"
$path = $request->file('logo')->store('/clients/logos','public');

// creating a canvas
$canvas = Image::canvas($width, $height);

// pass the right full path to the file. Remember that $path is a path inside app/public !
$image = Image::make(storage_path("app/public/" . $path))->resize($width, $height, 
    function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

$canvas->insert($image, 'center');

// pass the full path. Canvas overwrites initial image with a logo
$canvas->save(storage_path("app/public/" . $path . ".png"));
```

Canvas **needs full paths or chdir() to it**, it can be easy checked in e.g. `Intervention\Image\Image` source file (`./vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php`).

The `save` method contains simple `$saved = @file_put_contents($path, $data);` and no any `chdir` call.

Comment: aha, that seems it! Gonna try it out tomorrow at work and will give you your bounty. But that finally makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

With your code:

`$path = $request->file('logo')->store('/clients/logos','public');`

the returned `$path` is relative to your storage path.

You need to provide a fully qualified path to the public storage directory.

This can be achieved by using the helper function [storage_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-storage-path) so you use `storage_path($path)` instead of just `$path`

Therefore your code should look like this:

```
$path = $request->file('logo')->store('/clients/logos','public');

$canvas = Image::canvas($width, $height);
$image = Image::make(storage_path('app/'.$path))->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint)
{
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

$canvas->insert($image, 'center');
$canvas->save(storage_path('app/'.$path));

$this->logo_path = 'app/'.$path;
```

It is worth mentioning that this has not been tested but I would assume this is your issue.

**Edit:** Also, when using `Storage::disk('public')->url($path)`, it is going to return a `storage/` path relative to your public directory. Therefore, as the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/structure#the-storage-directory) mention:

> The `storage/app/public` directory may be used to store user-generated files, such as profile avatars, that should be publicly accessible. You should create a symbolic link at `public/storage` which points to this directory. You may create the link using the `php artisan storage:link` command.

Might help you down the track when you want to serve up that image in your view.

Comment: That makes sense, but didn't solve the issue, got the same 'Image not readable error' , but now referring to this path: `home/vagrant/php-resq/storage/clients/logos/ObaIpvgexGPcOStz0jaU73BJ8AUDp2ME85lUpMoY.jpeg` again the 'app' is not showing in that path

Comment: Then you just need to prepend ```app/``` to your path and that should work. The reason you are getting ```Image not readable``` is because you are not providing the correct path.

Comment: Adding app, seems like a hacky solution, so not really gonna do that. Got it working without using canvas() gonna ad that to my first post, so maybe someone will find a solution based on that