# Image source not readable error in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I want to store the name of the photo in my database and move the image to public/images directory in laravel 5.3. I have done in following ways but I get an error as shown in the snapshot. I have went through this link but couldn't understand it.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032644/use-laravel-storage-with-image-intervention-canvas)

This is the error I got:[image]
This is the code I am having:

```
if($request->hasFile('photo')){
            $file = $request->file('photo');
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/',$file->getClientOriginalName());
            $img=Image::make(sprintf('images/%s', $file->getClientOriginalName()));
            $img->resize(300,300)->save();
            $athlete->athlete_photo = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        }
```

Comment: move the file after you do the changes to it..

Comment: If you could show me how to do that ??

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-image-upload-and-resize?page=1 check this article