# Where to upload product images in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, e-commerce

I am building an e-commerce application using Laravel framework. Which location is most suitable to upload product images, Slider images, Banner images and all dynamically uploaded images in frontend?

**storage/app/public**

**public/img**

If am going for **storage/app/public** location. How can I access those images to website frontend?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: storage/app/public and get using echo asset('storage/app/public');

Comment: You can use `php artisan storage:link` to "_Create a symbolic link from "public/storage" to "storage/app/public"_"

Comment: @kerbholz  so you are suggesting storage/app/public. It is an ecommerce application. more than 10000 products are going to be there. Any future issues or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your images in your `storage` directory.

This is the best place as you can use the `Storage` facade which makes it easy to store images. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem

You can also use the `Storage` facade the same way you would locally if you were to change your storage destination to a CDN (e.g. Amazon S3). You will just need to change the configuration in `config/filesystems.php` and the code to store the images will remain the same.

Once you do store the images in the storage directory you can expose them to the frontend by symlink-ing it using `php artisan storage:link` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration

This will create a symlink from your storage directory in to the public directory.

You can use the helper `asset` to retrieve the path to the image. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset

--

There are lots of examples on how to store files in the storage directory:

https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/file-upload-in-laravel-the-ultimate-guide/

https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-and-working-with-files-in-laravel

[How to save uploaded image to Storage in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990023/how-to-save-uploaded-image-to-storage-in-laravel)

Comment: very helpful information. I would like to retain original uploaded product images in one folder and edited(resized and watermarked) images to another folder.. is there any laravel packages to accomplish this? i mean ecommerce product image management.

Comment: from previous experience I would suggest https://github.com/Intervention/image. they have a guide to integrating with Laravel http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel

Comment: i'd also suggest https://packagist.org/ to look for php packages and https://packalyst.com/ for laravel specific packages

Comment: Thank you..Got it.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
public/img
```

then locate it in the front end with asset function

```
{{ asset('name_of_file') }}
```

Comment: is it a better way to put images outside root folder?. Any security vulnerabilities?

Comment: if you are really keen about security then you should put that in storage/app/public then locate with asset